# Using writeOGR on a list of SpatialPolygons

Tags: shapefile, r, rgdal, list

This question has been asked before, but I find the answer confusing since there are no reproducible examples that link the question and the answer, and the answer doesn't actually use the `writeOGR` function. 
[Use lapply and writeOGR to write multiple shapefiles within a list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283889/use-lapply-and-writeogr-to-write-multiple-shapefiles-within-a-list)

I have a list of spatial objects. I want to export all of the using `writeOGR`. How can I apply this function to the list of spatial objects?

The solution I've come up with applies `writeOGR` to the outer list element, and I suppose I need to apply it to the inner list element, but I don't know how to do this.

```
library(GISTools)
library(rgdal)
data(tornados)

torn_list <- list(torn, torn2)
lapply(torn_list, function(x) writeOGR(obj = x, dsn = "tempdir", layer = x, driver = "ESRI Shapefile"))
```

```
Error in as.character.default(layer) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Any suggestions?

---

To clarify, I do want to do this to a list of shape files that have different coordinate reference systems. I would like to create a different shapefile for every element of the list. I realize now I would need to have some way of making the "`layer =`" argument  for each element of this list as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to assign the spatial object itself as the name for the shapefile produced (the `layer` argument). Below an example that works for me

```
lapply(torn_list, function(x) writeOGR(obj = x, dsn = "tempdir", layer = as.character(round(runif(1,0,100),0)), driver = "ESRI Shapefile"))
```

the output will be shapefiles with random numbers. if you want the shapefiles to be named "torn" and "torned2", you will need to play with the layer argument so that `lapply` yields it in each of its "iterations"

Answer (score 1):

A shapefile can only have one layer, and a layer has to have the same geometry type and the same columns, and the same coordinate system.

If all those conditions are true, you can use `rbind` to make a larger spatial data frame and write that with `writeOGR`.

`torn` and `torn2` have different coordinate systems so you can't do this.

You can write multiple layers to a geopackage file. But no, not a shapefile.

Comment: I've added some clarification to my question in response to your answer.